# Hypervisors that support AIX as a guest OS?

Tags: virtualization, aix, hypervisor

I am trying to find out what hypervisors are out there that can support running AIX guests. I know that IBM PowerVM can do it, but I would like to explore other options.

There is also AIX WPARs (workload partitions) which work like Solaris Containers, but I would prefer full virtualization that isolates hardware from OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No hypervisors support AIX. Kind of.

AIX running on an IBM Power server isn't actually virtualized in the same way that ESXi/KVM/etc. would do. Everything is handled by hardware.

On top of that, you can use VIOS to do Virtual I/O, but that's ONLY the IO. And only if you need to do so.

The actual hypervisor is the hardware platform itself on Power.

Answer (score 3):

AIX is a hypervisor. You run LPARs inside it. WPARs are only really used for OS levels not supported as an LPAR, in my experience.

I'm pretty sure that IBM won't license anyone to use AIX on anything other than the hardware they sell it on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any.  Isn't that link to a port of Qemu to run on AIX, rather than a port of Qemu that allows you to run AIX itself?

Comment: You could be right. I will edit it out.